# How to implement syntax highlighting?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, sublimetext2

I am making a website portfolio for one of my school project. Our task is to write some code (lets say in Python) which produces mostly images. Then we have to put those images on our website and add the code which produced them.

Now I just put the image on the webpage and add a link to github.com to access the code, but I would like to make better.

I am mostly coding in Sublime Text and I think the color schemes they use are pretty and helpful. I would like to somehow get the highlighted code from Sublime to view it on the webpage. It might look alike on the github.com, but without linking it. I want it actually on my web. If it can be done I think there might be two ways:

1. Get the code from Sublime and somehow put it highlighted on the web
2. Using probably textarea tags in html and some Javascript to recognise the language.

If it's not clear, my question is: Is it possible to achieve the behaviour described above? If so, how?

Comment: Since you used the JS tag, check out this library for what you need: http://highlightjs.org/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am trying all suggestions and this one seems nice. But I have some issues - first, some code have commentary, which are too long, can I handle that with some horizontal scroll bar? Next, I use monokai_sublime.min.css but I does not provide the same highlightening, e.g. boolean True, False, arguments in functions are not highlighted, I have checked, that the recognised language is right by adding class="python" to the code tag.

Comment: I don't know JavaScript, so I can't help you, unfortunately.

Comment: I figured it out!:) Just put the code in some `<div class="code">` and add css style `.code {overflow: auto;}`. And for the wrong highlighting - the authors do know about it, but it would be too much of a work to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [`ExportHtml`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ExportHtml) plugin available through Package Control. Once installed, right-click in your document, then select `Export -> HTML -> Sublime View: Color` and a new tab will be opened with the HTML in it. You can set the color scheme you wish to use in the preferences. I'll warn you that the generated HTML is pretty ugly, but you can just copy and paste into your web page, ensuring that you bring the JavaScript and CSS along with it.

Comment: Great, that's pretty much it. Although I have a few questions - since I am writing tens of scripts for the web is it possible to use one stylesheet and one javascript file without the need of producing it all over again for each script? Also can I format the output outside the actual *.html? E.g. it shows the time of the creation and the path to the exported file and I don't want it there, but deleting it manually(for each script) seems to much of a work. And lastly I don't need whole new html document, just lets say a new <div> that I would add to my page (no paste but include..)

Answer (score 1):

try [Ace Editor](http://ace.c9.io/)

Ace is an embeddable code editor written in JavaScript. It matches the features and performance of native editors such as Sublime, Vim and TextMate. It can be easily embedded in any web page and JavaScript application. Ace is maintained as the primary editor for Cloud9 IDE and is the successor of the Mozilla Skywriter (Bespin) project.

Comment: Although I didn't go this way it is still good to know something like this exits. Thanks a lot, I might as well use it in next projects.